# How to receive Push and Notification (Toast and tile) when app is closed windows universal 8.1 app

Tags: push-notification, toast, win-universal-app, background-task

Hi i want to receive push notification (toast and tile) when app is closed or in background. how to  do that i tried background task but unable to implement.

Comment: u can add them in the database and whenever app will be open u'll see the badge count and the notification too in notification tray or center

Comment: not understood can you you give me sample

Answer (score 0):

When the app is closed you can only get Raw push notifications if you add a background task for Raw push notifications